# GCDAsyncSocket readDataWithTimeout is not continuing to read data

Tags: ios, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

I am using GCDasyncsocket in my iOS app to send a string over a socket connection and then to read a string every second over the same socket connection.  I am also creating a second socket to the same server on a different port ad reading once a second there as well.

My write is working properly and the first few reads on each socket work properly, but then the connection appears to stop.

My current method of reading every second is to kick off the reads by calling

```
[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:1 tag:1];
[asyncSocket_Emove readDataWithTimeout:1 tag:2];
```

at the end of "didConnectToHost" and the similarly calling them again at the end of "didReadDatawithTag"

I can provide more details if needed, but does anyone have an idea why the socket is stopping?

Comment: First try replacing the timeout by -1, if it won't work then you'll need to put here more code, because it could be virtually anything...

Comment: Thanks, I think the issue I was having ended up being because of continuously polling the two sockets. Once I went back to only polling the 1 socket, it seems to be working better.  Does the Grand Central Dispatch part of GCDAsyncSocket handle the multi-threading of the two socket connections or is there a way that I'd need to tell it to go onto separate threads (or is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:1 tag:1];
```

with this

```
[asyncSocket readDataWithTimeout:-1 tag:1];
```

may work for you.